# html of a form sent through ajax, jquery adds endtag for it automatically so now form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am searching through database and sending back some information for products to the page. because data has so many details i have wrote the html in server side and send it back with ajax call. the only problem is that inside the table there is a form. server sends it correctly, if i say $(#resultshere).text(data.htmlres) it doesn't have any  right after my form but the moment I change it $(#resultshere).html(data.htmlres) it adds  right after my opening form tag. so now none of the inputs are in the form therefore it doesn't work properly.

I read that jquery.html checks and adds nodes itself so if there is form we should write $(#resultshere)[0].innerHTML = data.htmlres instead. it doesn't work it still ends the form immidiately.
also someone said add pre before and after that form but still doesn't work.

the code that I send with php laravel

```
$htmlres .='      
<thead>               
 <tr>
<th>row 1</th>                    
<th>row 2</th>                    
<th>row 3</th>                    
<th>row 4</th>                                         
</tr>               
</thead>                
<tbody>';                
//$htmlres .='</pre>';

$htmlres .='<form action="'.route('details').'" method="post" >';
$htmlres .= csrf_field();
//some other inputs and rows are here. but even when i delete them and it's as this simple it doesn't work          
$htmlres .='</form>';            
//$htmlres .='</pre>';
```

///HTML PAGE is like this

```
<div  id="resultshere">              
<div id="loading-img">
<img src="spinner.gif">                
</div>        
</div>
```

////AJAX IS like this

```
 $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '/getdetails/' + id
success: function (data) {
//$("#resultshere")[0].innerHTML = data.htmlres;
$("#resultshere").html(data.htmlres);
}
```

///HTML that I get till the jquery .html is

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/gotodetails" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bvk28w2xooYNuZg2dTBTk1QYipbjGOjW9vviOigR"></form>
```

///BUT WHEN I call .html I get

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/gotodetails" method="post"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bvk28w2xooYNuZg2dTBTk1QYipbjGOjW9vviOigR">
```

so because of that nothing work. I expect the form tag to be in the place I put not just automatically be ended

Comment: It might be useful to show the code at your comment "//some other inputs and rows are here. but even when i delete them and it's as this simple it doesn't work ". It's likely that's where the problem is.

Comment: I think it just makes the question stuffed with unnecessary stuff. because as I said even when i delete everything in between and i just want those 2 form tags to be in the right place they won't

Comment: Did you realize that you're putting the form directly into a <tbody>? This may not have anything to do with your issue, but it is certainly not valid HTML.

Comment: Also, you are terminating the form yourself in the last line of your php file.

Comment: @DovRine Yes I was aware of the fact that it was in tbody but i didn't know that it's not a valid html. thank you. so you think if I start the form tag before the table and end it afterwards it would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a contrived, working example based on what you've provided. I tested it using the php dev server.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'getdetails.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#resultshere").html(data);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resultshere">
        <div id="loading-img">
            <img src="spinner.gif" alt="Loading...">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

getdetails.php

```
<?php

// mock testing functions
function route($route_name){
    return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/gotodetails';
}
function csrf_field(){
    return '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bvk28w2xooYNuZg2dTBTk1QYipbjGOjW9vviOigR">';
}
// end mock testing functions
$action = route('details');
$csrf = csrf_field();
$htmlres = <<<HTML
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>row 1</th>
            <th>row 2</th>
            <th>row 3</th>
            <th>row 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="{$action}" method="post" >
                    {$csrf}
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
HTML;

echo $htmlres;
```

This generates the following final document after loading:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'getdetails.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    $("#resultshere").html(data);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resultshere">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>row 1</th>
                    <th>row 2</th>
                    <th>row 3</th>
                    <th>row 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>                
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/gotodetails" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bvk28w2xooYNuZg2dTBTk1QYipbjGOjW9vviOigR">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, since you're using laravel, you shpuld be returning only the data and using your template language (blaze?) to generate the table.

Comment: I wanted to do that but the table is so complicated and has so many rows that only I would know(Even I don't know completely )  what had happened and if later some other developer wants to update this code it would be hell for them :)